# Passing the string value from view to controller sending only null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to send some data to controller but i always getting null value in parameter of controller . I look for solution but not reached to solution . Please provide some suggestion or help .

ajax call

```
 var submittedName = 1; 
 $.ajax(
  {
      url: '/api/monitor/Detailsfetch',
      type: "post",
      data: { 'submittedName': submittedName},
      success: function (data) {
          alert("passed");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(thrownError);}
  });
```

Controller part

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
  public ContentResult Detailsfetch(string submittedName)        
    {sone code here}`
```

Comment: you are not passing a string but an int. What happens is the error function called and in that case what's the error message?

Comment: if i pass some string instead of int , result is same and there is no error but the thing is when i put breakpoint on my controller it shows null value of the parameter .

Comment: try `type: "POST"` instead of `"post"`

Comment: it also dont make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments and what little information you have provided I'd guess that you route is not set up correctly. If you want to test this (assuming you have not changed the default rule). Try to rename the parameter to id (in both controller and JS). If that works then it's because your route is not configured

see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) for help in that case

basically you should have something like this in your `application_start`

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route {
    Url = "[controller]/[action]/[submittedName]",
    RouteHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler)
})
```

Comment: Thnxs for answer i renamed parameter to id .........and now i am gettting "Detailsfetch" as the value of parameter which is same as function name .............am i doing something really stupid !!

Comment: @user1260967 have you resolved the issue you commented about?

Comment: please elaborate a bit (as an edit to the question) e.g. how's your routing setup, where do you get the mentioned error etc

Comment: when i passed the data it is showing properly in browser as "Parameters bla bla and Sources = bla+bla  " but on the controller side i am getting the null as parameter value , but once i rename parameter as id ...it is showing the parameter value same as method name .

Comment: @user1260967 it is a routing error and with out the exact path _and_ the routing information it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario not able to send parameter value using data: { 'submittedName': submittedName} So an alternative coud be loke to pass parameter data in URL itself

```
/api/monitor/Detailsfetch/?submittedName="+somename+"",
```

Hope this could help some body !!